# DigitalOcean Kubernetes Cluster is unreachable

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, digital-ocean

My app runs kubernetes cluster with 2 droplets. But now kubernetes throws 500 error and does not work. I tried to remove kubernetes and its droplets but then it gives me this error: “13 INTERNAL: dialing for agent, agent unavaiable.”

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer to summarise the topic:

The same question was asked on [digital ocean forum](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/kubernetes-cluster-is-unreachable). The community user [bobbyiliev](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/users/bobbyiliev) has provided the answer:

> Hello,
>
> Do you see any errors in the logs? And also if you check the status of your nodes do you get any more information rather than the 500 error?
>
> What I could suggest is following the steps from this tutorial here and setting up an unmanaged cluster from scratch:
>
> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-kubernetes-cluster-using-kubeadm-on-ubuntu-20-04
>
> Alternatively, you could give the Managed Clusters a try which would allow you to not have to worry about the server management at all:
>
> https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/quickstart/
>
> Best,
> Bobby

Generally, in your situation, actually creating a new cluster from scratch may be the best solution. Another will be to look at the logs for exact information on what doesn't work. See also [this similar question](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/500-internal-server-error-2).